# Finding records older than a minute

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a users table which consists of

some columns like `name,age,created_at`

created_at contains time in unix timestamps format (epoch).

I basically want to create a query to show all queries that are older than 1 minute.

I tried the following `SELECT * FROM users WHERE created_at > NOW() - INTERVAL '1 minutes';`

But i got the following error :

> operator does not exist: double precesion > timestamp with time zone

Comment: I'm confused.  You say `created_at` is a `date`.  That has no time component.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  sorry typo

Comment: The later just updated.

Comment: https://blog.sql-workbench.eu/post/epoch-mania/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, `created_at` is actually a Unix timestamp.  That means it is measured in seconds, so you can do:

```
where created_at < extract(epoch from now() - interval '1 minute')
```